# In Java how to refer subclass variable without declaring that variable in parent class?

Tags: java, class, oop, polymorphism, parent-child

```
public class MyTest {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.print();
    }
}

class A {
    private final int x = 5;

    protected int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(getX());
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private final int x = 10;

    @Override
    protected int getX() {
        return x;
    }


}
```

In this example, I need to print subclass value in the parent class.
It is working fine. No issue.
Now it is printing 10.
But I do not want to define that property in the parent `class A`.

Because in this example this `x` datatype is very simple. So no issue.
But in real-time I want to use other datatype which may be another Class variable or `List<something>` which have huge data.

So ultimately I do not wish to store that value in `Class A`.
Because it is redundant data. It will slow down in my Hibernate thing.
Please let me know, how to achieve this without declaring variable in parent class. But I still need to use subclass variable in parent class.

Comment: Then don't declare it there! Remove `x` from `A` and everything should still work.

Comment: @Sweeper, it won't work because parent's `getX` uses it

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Then remove `getX` from `A` as well. I don't see the point of having it there. And move `print` to `B`. `A` is essentially not needed.

Comment: @Sweeper, providing an interface for subclasses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make abstract your class A and the getX(); method.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        b.print();
    }
}

abstract class A {

    protected abstract int getX();

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(getX());
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private final int x = 10;

    @Override
    protected int getX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

and override the toString method in place of your print method

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return String.valueOf(getX());
}
```

the final code

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}

abstract class A {

    protected abstract int getX();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(getX());
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private static final int X = 10;

    @Override
    protected int getX() {
        return X;
    }
}
```

you could also define as static your x variable

But as say Andrew Tobilko you can consider also to use an interface if A doesn't represent a stateful entity.

It's certainly the best solution for your case, mix the use of an interface and an abstract class

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}

interface MyInterface {
    int getX();
}

abstract class A implements MyInterface{
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(getX());
    }
}

class B extends A {
    private static final int X = 10;

    @Override
    public int getX() {
        return X;
    }
}
```

Comment: no it can't. an Object method can't be overrided in an interface. but we can defined a default method print and make a trait in j8

Answer (score 2):

You need the `getX` within the parent class, but you don't have information enough to implement this method there.

You can declare this class as `abstract` and mark the method with `abstract` as well. Doing that, you are handing the responsibility of method implementation over its subclasses and preventing from parent field declaration.

If the `A` doesn't describe any state (only actions/methods), you should consider replacing it with an interface. At the current state, it is the case.

Answer (score 1):

You could make the parent class abstract, eliminate the property in the parent class, make getX() abstract, and then leave print() as concrete. Then just use the concrete implementation of getX() in the child class.